# Haar Measure: Unimodular Locally Compact Groups

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following problem: "Let $G$ be a locally compact group, all of whose normal subgroups are contained in $Z(G)$. Prove that $G$ is unimodular."

My attempt at attacking the problem was to consider the homomorphism $\Delta:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\times}_+$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
\int_G f(yx)d_rx = \Delta(y)\int_Gf(x)d_rx
\end{equation*}
where $d_rx$ is a right Haar measure on $G$. Then $G$ will be unimodular if and only if $\Delta = 1$. However, I am having some difficulty showing that this holds. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing proper normal subgroups is meant, to keep the problem from being trivial?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but note that $\ker(\Delta)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (you need to show it's $G$), and $\int_G f(yxy^{-1}) \, d_r x = \Delta(y) \int_G f(x) \, d_r x$. Maybe that could help.

Comment: Harry Altman: You are correct of course.

Comment: Joel Cohen: A similar argument shows that $Z(G) \leq \ker \Delta$ so that certainly helps.